# How to prevent movement in this 3 DOF setup?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms, fasteners, servo

I have a 3DOF platform that I'm trying to make more stable. It's difficult to explain in words what the issue is so I've added a GIF below.

[image]

Any ideas of how I can get rid of this wobble? The DOF arm tends to cave inwards. I know it's being caused by the very small gap between the screw and the channel but is there any way to prevent this? Since the servo's I'm using don't have a dual shaft going through and through I can't modify the servo arm to be a inverted-U attached on both ends of the servo.

Comment: Build to smaller tolerances and if that does not work, change the design.

Comment: I second @SolarMike’s comment.  You could purchase different shim stock sizes and cut a very small piece to fill the space between the two parts, but that’s only a band-aid.

Comment: Fill up the play with e.g. CA glue?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your design correctly you extend the existing play in the mechanism.

If you can’t eliminate the play then you can try to minimise it.
See the locking pliers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locking_pliers) as an example to reduce the play. The disadvantage of this principe is the distance decrease.